# Countif and logical operation in Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

In My spreadsheet, I want to count how many invoices are not paid and overdue. So for that I Count tose who are not paid like this:

```
=COUNTIF(F4:F256, "nein")
```

But how can I make a condition only count if "date" is lower than today? Normally I would iterate over it but don't know how in the spreadsheet.

The table looks for example like this:

[image]

Comment: you can use the COUNTIFS function, which allows multiple conditions (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en)  - (you can also use the TODAY() function in the conditions to get the current date (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984?hl=en&ref_topic=3105385)

Comment: tried this:

`=COUNTIFS(F4:F256, "nein", E4:E256, is LOWER(TODAY()))` but returned error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(F4:F256; "nein"; E4:E256; "<"&TODAY())
```

Comment: seems not quite correct. It counts 0 ... but should return 1

Comment: its fixed. today returned date like this 07/31/2019 ... had to change that. works now. thanks